# AWK - does an if condition calculate an array input

Tags: awk, gawk

## Question

so I have the following line of code:

```
if (sum[msg,h]/summsg[msg,h] != 0)
printf ("%9.2f\n",sum[msg,h]/summsg[msg,h])
```

`msg` is a message array holds 10 distinct values
`hr` holds all hours present in a log file.
the `sum[]` array is addind together values of a field  (`sum[$5,$3] += $11`)
and the `summsg[]` array is counting the number of lines (`summsg[$5,$3]++`)

This is retuning a `fatal: division by zero attempted` error, but I thorght that `awk` would evaluate the `sum[msg,h]/summsg[msg,h] != 0` and then continue.

I have also tried checking for each of the values with the following code:

```
if (sum[msg,h] != 0 || summsg[msg,h] != 0)
printf ("%9.2f\n",sum[msg,h]/summsg[msg,h])
```

But this is stopping my hour calculation as I think it is picking up the leading 0 's on hours 00-09 and returning false.

I can provide the full code if needed.

Any ideas?

## Comment Update

As per the comments, they were typos, corrected them and they didn't make a difference.

### Sample input file

```
message1 01 10
message2 01 01
message2 01 05
message1 01 15
message1 01 05
message1 02 03
message1 02 06
message2 02 10
message2 02 20
message2 02 05
```

> This is a made up input file

The code to reflect the input file would be as follows:

```
{
msg_type[$1]++
sum[$1,$2] += $3
summsg[$1,$2]++
}
END {
 for (msg in msg_type) {
    print msg
    for (h = 0; h <= 23; h++) {
        if (sum[msg,h] != 0 || summsg[msg,h] != 0)
        printf ("%9.2f\n",sum[msg,h]/summsg[msg,h])
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't use a variable `hr`; it uses a variable `h`.  Yet your description uses `hr`.  Is this disconnect/typo the source of the problem?  You mention `summsg[$5,%3]++` but the `%` in that is a typo.  Can you provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) using say 3 columns of data instead of 11, and provide sample input and output data?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have tried to do individual if statements and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks for adding the MCVE code.  I'm not getting a divide by zero from the code because of the condition.  Note that the problem is probably the difference between "01" and "1" as the indexes in the array — they're strings, not pure numbers, in `awk`.

Comment: You took the access part of the code I posted but not the populate part. Look again and notice the `$2+0` when I populate the array - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38020663/1745001. The general way to protect yourself from divide-by-zero is with a ternary expression like  `print (denom ? num / denom : "NaN")` or similar.

Comment: Do you mean 'AWK 3.1.7' rather than 'AWK 1.3.7' in the title?  Your other questions are for 3.1.7, it seems.  It would be reasonable to use GNU Awk 3.1.7 to identify the version more precisely.   That dates from 2009.  Are you sure you shouldn't upgrade to 3.1.8 (from 2010), or more likely to 4.1.3 from 2015?  I think it would be best to drop the version from the titles, and simply add a paragraph "I'm using GNU Awk 3.1.7 and I can't upgrade, even though it is quite an old version" or something similar.  Identifying the version is good; it doesn't necessarily need to be in the title, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I did mean AWK 3.1.7  I will remove that from the title as you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your MCVE code, the problem is that you indexed the arrays with `01` or `02` while loading them, but are trying to extract the data with `1` or `2` (no leading zero).  You have to fix that.  For example:

```
{
  msg_type[$1]++
  sum[$1,$2] += $3
  summsg[$1,$2]++
  #print "type:", $1, "hr:", $2, "value:", $3
}
END {
  for (msg in msg_type) {
    print msg
    for (i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
      if (i < 10)
        h = "0" i
      else
        h = i
      #print "  ", msg, h, sum[msg,h], summsg[msg,h]
      if (sum[msg,h] != 0 || summsg[msg,h] != 0)
        printf("%9.2f\n", sum[msg,h]/summsg[msg,h])
    }
  } 
}
```

For the sample input, the output becomes:

```
message1
    10.00
     4.50
message2
     3.00
    11.67
```

I think you should probably print the hour too, but that's your choice.

Comment: you sir are a legend.