# AWK - if and printf, before or within

Tags: awk, gawk

I have the following `printf`

```
printf ("%-6s\t%6.3f\n",msg,sum[msg]/count[msg])
```

the arrays to this are as follows:

```
sum[$2] += $3
count[$2]++
```

`$2 = test1`
`$3 = 0 - 9` on different lines at random

I am to do a if statement to say if either `sum[msg]` or `count[msg]` == 0 then replace with `-`

I am not sure if I have to do the following:

```
if (count[msg] == 0 || sum[msg] == 0) {
printf ("%-6s\t-\n",msg)
}
```

or is it possible to put the if within the `printf` like the following:

```
printf ("%-6s\t%6.3f\n",msg,if (count[msg] == 0 || sum[msg] == 0) {print -} else sum[msg]/count[msg])
```

Also if the actual `sum[$2] += $3` has no matching rows will that return `0` or `null`

all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I already told you how to do that in your previous question. See my comment under http://stackoverflow.com/q/38023336/1745001. Given [your recent history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3963654/glenn-lynam) of posting questions every few hours you seem to be putting **very** little effort into trying to solve your problems yourself or even trying to understand the solutions you're being given and instead immediately posting a new question every time you hit something you might have to think about for a few seconds. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @EdMorton With all due respect, I am spending a good few hours on an issue and I am constantly referencing/checking [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html). I do admit that I am relatively new to `awk` and that I don't fully understand the ins and outs of all things but in regards to your comment "I already told you..." I don't think that you have. Before I post a question I do go over all of the questions that I have previously posted and what I am trying to do isn't to do with 'the leading 0' as the resolution to the stackoverflow.com/q/38023336/1745001 was.

Comment: Look again. The solution I provided to http://stackoverflow.com/q/38020217/1745001 handles the leading zero by `+0` when populating the array as I reminded you in the comments under http://stackoverflow.com/q/38023336/1745001 so you didn't have to ask that question, and also in those comments I told you "The general way to protect yourself from divide-by-zero is with a ternary expression like `print (denom ? num / denom : "NaN")` or similar." which is the solution to the specific question you are now asking. Read the book to get a foundation and you won't spend so much time wondering/asking.

Comment: @EdMorton ok that is fine. I admit that I did overlook the `+0` in http://stackoverflow.com/q/38020217/1745001 but I don't fully understand the ternary expression you used. Please could you type out the `print` statement as an `if` as my shorthand is terrible?

Comment: `if (denom) print num / denom; else print "NaN"`. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf "%-6s\t%s\n",msg,(sum[msg]*count[msg]?sprintf("%6.3f",sum[msg]/count[msg]):"-")
```

but please do read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to get a foundation so you don't have to keep asking for help every step of the way.

Comment: Can I confirm that `sum[msg]*count[msg]` is just checking to see if that is `0` or not?